# "!--" added automatically to <?php tag and broke the code

Tags: php

I finished a project on my Linux VM and pushed it on to a github repo so that my colleague can set up another VM to host it. My code, as ugly as it is, was working but when it was hosted on the VM, the code broke. After a while, I found out that somehow the php tag from my code turns from `<?php` to `<!--?php` and the `>` turned to `-->` and made the first part of my code a comment as in the picture. Does anyone know what causes this issue and how I can resolve this issue? Thank you so much.
[image]

Comment: There are too many unknowns here to figure it out. Is your IDE changing it? What are you using to push it into git? If it's the desktop app, does it look correct in the changes preview? Does it look correct in the repository itself?

Comment: @aynber Thank you for your feedback. I use VSCode to develop it but in my local VM machine, I used XAMPP as it was easier for me to set up and manage the database. The new hosted VM that my colleague set up the database using MySQL and Apache. To push the code from my local VM, I used the Linux terminal, and to pull the code my colleague recommended Putty. The code shown on Github repo and when I use VI to open the file do not show the extra ```!--``` and ```--``` but when I inspect it with a browser, those were added somehow.

Comment: This most typically happens when PHP wasn't executed at all, see mentioned duplicate for details. It is the browser _making_ these tags into comments, because it doesn't know what they are supposed to mean.